# How to test an API with the basic auth using YAML, tavern and pytest

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pytest, tavern

I am implementing a Delete API which requires basic authentication before deleting any user. following is my code for basic auth and deleting a user which works perfectly fine via curl commands.

```
def auth_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if(request.authorization != None and request.authorization["username"] != None and request.authorization["password"] != None):
            username = request.authorization["username"]
            password = request.authorization["password"]
        else:
            return make_response('User does not exists.\n' 'Please provide user credentials', 401,
                    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})
        if check_auth(username, password):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return  make_response('Could not verify the credentials.\n' 'Please use correct credentials', 401,
                    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})
    return decorated

def check_auth(username, password):
    cur = get_db().cursor().execute("SELECT user_name, password from users WHERE user_name=?", (username,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row and row[0] == username and pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, row[1]):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#curl command to execure delete function - curl -u parag:parag --include --verbose --request DELETE --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:5000/delete_user/
@app.route('/delete_user', methods=['DELETE'])
@auth_required
def api_delete_user():
        if request.method == 'DELETE':
            status_code:bool = False
        cur = get_db().cursor()
        username = request.authorization["username"]
        try:
            cur.execute("UPDATE users SET active_status =? WHERE user_name=?",(0, username,))
            if(cur.rowcount >= 1):
                get_db().commit()
                status_code = True
        except:
            get_db().rollback()
            status_code = False
        finally:
            if status_code:
                return jsonify(message="Passed"), 201
            else:
                return jsonify(message="Fail"), 409
```

I have created a  YAML file to test the above delete API but I am unable to add basic authentication in it. following is my YAML file for testing the delete API.

```
test_name: Delete existing user

stages:
  - name: Make sure you delete existing user
    request:
      url: http://localhost:5000/delete_user
      json:

      method: DELETE
      headers:
        content-type: application/json
    response:
      status_code: 201
      body:
        message: Passed
      save:
        $ext:
          context:
            parameters:
              auth_required:
                username: parag
                password: bhingre
```

Above file does not help me delete user by basic authenticating before deleting user.
Please let me know if any solutions or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try to add Authorization in your header & read the Authorization value from header.
It worked for me.

```
headers:
  content-type: application/json
  Authorization: "Basic trydtfjgbyugvyujbbyy"
```